# Does a Java class exist that provides arbitrary-depth nesting for conversion to a JSON object?

Tags: java, json, forms, collections, tree

I suspect there must be some Java class or library I'm overlooking that provides the functionality I'm looking for:

My Select Input contents can get quite large, and I want to display them hierarchically to improve readability (see example below).  Nesting can achieve any arbitrary depth.

```
Weapons
  Swords
    1-handed
      Katanas
      Bokin
    2-handed
      Zweihänder
  Spears
    Angon
Food
  Meat
    Fish
      Angel
  Pasta
...
```

I'm not making use of `OptGroup` because I need the collections to be selectable themselves.  First I searched the web for references a Java tree class.  Not finding anything, I recursively collected the data for my options up on the server-side into a HashMap of HashMaps of HashMaps, all the way down, and then calling `new Gson().toJson(data)`. On the client side I recursively traversed this by calling keys on each value, padding the text to match depth.  This worked for a while, until I realized I need my Option values to be different from the Option text.  Now I'm at a loss again, because the `HashMap` collection doesn't look like it will handle this extra dimension.

I've not tried to write JSON by hand before, but I think the JSON I want to send over now might look something like this:

```
{
   'name' : 'Weapons',
   'id' : 45,
   {
      'name' : 'Swords',
      'id' : 32,
      {
        'name' : '1-handed',
        'id' : 341,
        {
          'name' : 'Katanas',
          'id' : 3
        },
        {
          'name' : 'Bokin',
          'id' : 9
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Minus an existing solution out there, I think my next plan would be to make a class that stores its own option data plus an array of instances of that self-same class. On the deep end of solutions maybe I could learn how to format JSON correctly and use StringBuilder and recursion to construct the JSON object.  Isn't there some solution to this problem, though, that makes use of off-the-shelf libraries?

Comment: I'd prefer [FasterXML/Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) - [`JsonGenerator`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.9.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html) can be used to generate correct JSON easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the *a* right track with `Map<String, Object>`, since that can nest arbitrarily deep.

You need to name the list of nested nodes, though, e.g. call it `children`, but you can of course name it whatever you want:

```json
{
    "name": "Weapons",
    "id": 45,
    "children": [{
        "name": "Swords",
        "id": 32,
        "children": [{
            "name": "1-handed",
            "id": 341,
            "children": [{
                "name": "Katanas",
                "id": 3
            }, {
                "name": "Bokin",
                "id": 9
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

In Java though, a better way would be to use type-safe objects, instead of plain maps:

```java
class Node {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<Node> children;

    // constructor, getters and setters here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for talking me down.  Implementing a custom Node class was not the monster it was shaping up to be in my head.